# Linker issue with oneAPI if I use the -ipo flag

Tags: c++, cmake, intel-oneapi

I'm using oneAPI (intel's compiler) and ran into issues using the `-ipo` flag when compiling. The setup:

- `my_lib` project: static lib
- `my_test`: executable that links to `my_lib`

Files:
`my_lib`:

- `main.cpp`

  ```
  int foo() {
      return 0;    
  }
  ```
- `CMakeLists`

  ```
  project(my_lib CXX)
  add_library(my_lib STATIC main.cpp)
  ```

`my_test`:

- `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;
  int main() {
      cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  }
  ```
- CMakeLists

  ```
  project(my_test)

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ipo")

  add_subdirectory(my_lib)

  add_executable(my_test main.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(my_test my_lib)
  ```

Folder structure looks like this:

- main.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt  // this one's for `my_test`
- my_lib

  - main.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt

I'd run `cmake` on `my_test`'s CMakeLists.txt, then run `make`. Thee error I get is:

```
...
...
[100%] Linking CXX executable my_test
/usr/bin/ld: my_lib/my_lib.a: error adding symbols: archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
icpx: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_test.dir/build.make:98: my_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: CMakeFiles/my_test.dir/all] Error 2
```

Any ideas why I can't link this simple code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read somewhere that the default GNU linker wouldn't be able to make sense of binaries built using the Intel compiler with the `-ipo` flag on. I switched to using the LLVM linker and it worked.

To turn that on, I added this to the CMakeLists file

```
add_link_options("-fuse-ld=lld")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've raised a [thread](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/Linker-issue-with-oneAPI-if-I-use-the-ipo-flag/td-p/1513435) in Intel Communities.

You can try building using CMake after making the below changes in CMakeLists.txt. This command can be used to enable IPO with the icpx compiler.

```
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ipo")  
set(CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION ON)
```

Please refer to the below link for more information.
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20818